# Unable to get parent controller data inside the component's template html in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am unable to display the name of all countries inside my `template html`. I have function in parent controller that stores the list of all the added countries. Using `component bindings`, how can I pass the label of parent `controller` to the `template` so that `template` can `iterate` all the objects in a `list` and display value. I have attached the code snippets. I would appreciate if anyone can point me where I am making a mistake. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="countriesApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="First Angular App">
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, Javascript, AngularJs">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <title>Very basic AngularJs component example</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="addCountriesController as countryCtrl">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Add Country" ng-model="countryCtrl.country">
        <input type="button" value="Add" ng-click="countryCtrl.addCountry(countryCtrl.country)">
        <add-countries-component countryObj="countryCtrl"></add-countries-component>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The `template html` is:

```
<div>
    <ol>
        <li ng-repeat = "country in countryObj.allCountries">
            {{country.name}}
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

my `app.js` file is:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module("countriesApp", [])
        .component("addCountriesComponent", { 
            templateUrl: "addcountries.html"
            , bindings: { 
                countryObj : "<"
            }
        })
        .controller("addCountriesController", addCountriesControllerFunction)
        .service("addCountriesService", addCountriesServiceFunction);

    addCountriesControllerFunction.$inject = ["addCountriesService"]
    function addCountriesControllerFunction(addCountriesService){
        var controller = this;
        var service = addCountriesService;
        controller.addCountry = function(country){
            return service.addCountries(country);
        }
        controller.allCountries = service.allCountries;
    } 

    function addCountriesServiceFunction(){
        var service = this;
        var countries = [];
        service.addCountries = function(country){
            var country = {
                name: country
            }
            countries.push(country);
        }
        service.allCountries = countries;
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a couple things going on here.

- Suggest only passing in the data that is needed for that component.
- If you use one word lowercase property name you don't have to worry about cameCase to snake-case resolution.
- Like it or not each component has it's own controller so gotta grab the data from there.
- The name you provide in the `bindings` property describe how the passed in data will be named in your controller.

Here's a working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Temizy?p=preview).  I removed the service from this example as I think it only confuses the point, since how the data got in the controller is irrelevant.

or else...

**Your code modified (YMMV):**

index.html

```
<!-- It's good practice to pass in only the data you need. -->
<add-countries-component countries="countryCtrl.allCountries"></add-countries-component>
```

app.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    function AddCountriesComponentController() {};  // <--- Create component controller

    angular.module("countriesApp", [])
        .component("addCountriesComponent", { 
            templateUrl: "addcountries.html",
            controller: AddCountriesComponentController,
            controllerAs: AddCountriesCompCtrl,  // defaults to $ctrl if not provided.
            bindings: { 
                countries: "<"   // 1-way binding whatever gets passed in as coutryObj in ComponentController.
            }
        })
    ...

})();
```

template:

```
<div>
    <ol>
        <!-- Grab the countries from the Components own controller. -->
        <li ng-repeat = "country in AddCountriesCompCtrl.allCountries">
            {{country.name}}
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

`<add-countries-component countryObj="countryCtrl"></add-countries-component>`

to

`<add-countries-component country-obj="controller.allCountries"></add-countries-component>`

And

```
<div>
    <ol>
        <li ng-repeat = "country in countryObj">
            {{country.name}}
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

And

```
ng-controller="addCountriesController as controller"
```